# HTML table with two sticky columns and headers (using only CSS)

Tags: html, css, css-tables, fixed-header-tables

I'm struggling to get two fixed columns and headers using a HTML table + scrollable body.
I've searched a lot and found these approaches:

- [this (only 1 fixed column/header)](https://jsfiddle.net/RMarsh/bzuasLcz/3/)
- and [this (only 1 fixed column/header; no table markup)](https://codepen.io/MaxArt2501/pen/qLCmE)
- and I've also [created my own solution](https://jsfiddle.net/9poy57Lm/) using a library, which works fine, but I don't like how the html table tag markups getting messed up & moreover initializing the `colModal` is not that good since I've a dynamic amount of columns.

Since I am not satisfied with any of these solutions, I would like to know if there is a chance to get this job done only using CSS?

Comment: Can you clarify what *tag markups getting messed up* means?  Also the `colModal` is just `JSON` -- It can be dynamically set in a variable, and the function re-initialized to compensate for any issues you have with dynamic tables.

Comment: With "messed up" I mean e.g. duplicate nodes. Every node is duplicated using the library in my solution. So having e.g. duplicate ids in HTML markup is very very bad - but you get this kind of issues using the library.

Comment: Would this HTML / CSS solution work? --> http://jsfiddle.net/0qpegqzc/2/

Comment: No, if I see it correct, only the headers are fixed, but not two columns (see my solution for comparison^^)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that it's possible to achieve what I want only using CSS. So I've found another library called [TableHeadFixer](https://www.jqueryscript.net/table/jQuery-Plugin-For-Fixed-Table-Header-Footer-Columns-TableHeadFixer.html) which does not duplicate nodes and IDs in your HTML markup.

So I came up with this final solution:
https://jsfiddle.net/4s53f124/2/

All you have to do is to call the `tableHeadFixer` method of the library (and if you want to some CSS adjusting):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#fixTable").tableHeadFixer({"left": 2});
 });
```

Comment: Yep, unfortunately, but I'm not sure how this could be achieved without fixed width/height. 
Did you solve it using variable width/height?

Comment: I used position sticky on the thead with top 0 and position sticky on the first td and second td with left 0 and calculated width of the first column respectively, this wont work on IE and opera mini though

Answer (score 1):

The closest I came is [this](https://codepen.io/carbonbased/pen/vPYZrK?editors=1100).

No HTML table markup and no IE support.
I used `position: sticky` on the header and the first column.

The dimensions of the table are variable, but the widths of the cells need to be supplied.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this with only html and css is to add a second table within the first column where you add the first 2 columns and do the same way for the body. Maybe not the most elegant solution but it does the job with pure html and css.

```css
thead tr>th {
  background: #eee;
  position: sticky;
  padding: .5rem;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.sticky-column {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.sticky-column tr>th {
  border-bottom: 0px solid black;
}

thead tr>.sticky-column {
  z-index: 3;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

tbody tr>.sticky-column {
  background: #fff;
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<table id="board">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="sticky-column">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th> <strong>Column 1</strong>
            </th>
            <th>
              <strong>Column 2</strong>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </th>
      <th>
        <strong>Column 3</strong>
      </th>
      <th>
        <strong>Column 4</strong>
      </th>
      <th>
        <strong>Column 5</strong>
      </th>
      <th>
        <strong>Column 6</strong>
      </th>
      <th>
        <strong>Column 7</strong>
      </th>
      <th>
        <strong>Column 8</strong>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="sticky-column">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              Content 1
            </td>
            <td>
              Content 2
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 6
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 7
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 8
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="sticky-column">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              Content 1
            </td>
            <td>
              Content 2
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 6
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 7
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 8
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="sticky-column">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              Content 1
            </td>
            <td>
              Content 2
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 6
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 7
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 8
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="sticky-column">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              Content 1
            </td>
            <td>
              Content 2
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 6
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 7
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 8
      </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="sticky-column">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              Content 1
            </td>
            <td>
              Content 2
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 6
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 7
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 8
      </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="sticky-column">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              Content 1
            </td>
            <td>
              Content 2
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 6
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 7
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 8
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="sticky-column">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              Content 1
            </td>
            <td>
              Content 2
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 6
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 7
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 8
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="sticky-column">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              Content 1
            </td>
            <td>
              Content 2
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 6
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 7
      </td>
      <td>
        Content 8
      </td>

    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```